# Not matching the correct overload in C#

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, parameters, overload-resolution

I have the following program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;


class Program
{

    public static string Foo<T>(params T[] items)
    {
        return "A";
    }

    public static string Foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        return "B";
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        List<int> items = new List<int>(){0,1,23};

        Console.WriteLine(Foo(items));
        Console.WriteLine(Foo("XXX"));

    }
}
```

which outputs

```
A
A
```

rather than

```
B
A
```

Given that List is a subclass of IEnumerable why does the generic `params` form match earlier with the compiler and give an unexpected answer.

Comment: Have close-voted after answering - I hadn't spotted the dupe before, but I've left my answer here as it approaches it *slightly* differently to my answer in the other question :)

Answer (score 4):

When the "better function member" part of the spec (section 7.5.3.2) is invoked, the parameter list being considered is in the *expanded* form (because the first method is only applicable in its expanded form). At that point, you're comparing two invocations like this:

```
public static string Foo<T>(T[] items)
Foo(new[] { items });
```

and

```
public static string Foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
Foo(items);
```

The conversion from `List<int>[]` to `List<int>[]` is a "better conversion" than the conversion from `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`, so we don't get as far as the tie-breakers which *would* otherwise prefer the normal form over the expanded form.

Comment: Applied to our example, this means lhe line `Console.WriteLine(Foo(items));` calls `Foo<List<int>>(params List<int>[] items)` instead of `Foo<int>(params int[] items)` or `Foo<int>(IEnumerable<int> items)`.

Comment: @Medinoc: Yes, exactly. (I think the OP knows what's being called, and is merely curious as to why that's the case.)